# Concatenating two int arrays using memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy

This might get long, but essentially what I'm trying to do is concatenate two int arrays: `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` so that the result is `[1,2,3,4]`.

My code is my proposed solution to this [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double findMedianSortedArrays(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size) {
    int totalLen = nums1Size + nums2Size;
    int halflen = totalLen/2;
    int INTSIZE = sizeof(int);
    int* arr = malloc(INTSIZE*totalLen);
    int c1 = 0;
    int c2 = 0;

    // loop through lists to combine them into a sorted array
    for (int i = 0; i < halflen+1; i++) {
        if (nums1[c1] > nums2[c2]) {
            arr[i] = nums2[c2];
            c2++;
        } else {
            arr[i] = nums1[c1];
            c1++;
        }

        // PART THAT BREAKS
        // If we've exhausted all of nums1, concat nums2 to the end of it
        if (c1 >= nums1Size) {
            memcpy(arr+(i*INTSIZE), nums2, INTSIZE*(nums2Size-c2)); 
            break;
        }
    }

    // find and return median
    if ((int)halflen < halflen) {
        return (arr[halflen] + arr[halflen-1]) / 2;
    } else {
        return arr[halflen];
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it? The error given to me is:

```
================================================================= 
==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000070 at pc 0x7fbe96801784 bp 0x7ffff6c07570 sp 0x7ffff6c06d20 
WRITE of size 8 at 0x602000000070 thread T0 
    #0 0x7fbe96801783 (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.5+0x3e783) 
    #4 0x7fbe954212e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0) 

Address 0x602000000070 is a wild pointer. 
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.5+0x3e783) 
Shadow bytes around the buggy address: 
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa[fa]fa 
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes): 
Addressable: 00 
Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
Heap left redzone: fa 
Freed heap region: fd 
Stack left redzone: f1 
Stack mid redzone: f2 
Stack right redzone: f3 
Stack after return: f5 
Stack use after scope: f8 
Global redzone: f9 
Global init order: f6 
Poisoned by user: f7 
Container overflow: fc 
Array cookie: ac 
Intra object redzone: bb 
ASan internal: fe 
Left alloca redzone: ca Right alloca redzone: cb 
==30==ABORTING
```

(I also have no idea what much of this error is trying to tell me, unfortunately)

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. You're not concatenating, you're merging while maintaining a sorted invariant. In any event, why are you looping to `halfLen+1` only? If there are 30 items in the first input, and 10 in the second, why would you stop the loop when you copy 21 items?  Seems like you'd want to run to the minimum of the two input lengths, then `memcpy` the rest from the longer of the two inputs.

Comment: What happens if you exhaust `nums2` before you exhaust `nums1`?

Comment: But from a wider perspective, why are you performing a merge at all?  It looks like you already have almost everything you need to find the median without actually merging the arrays.  Consider, do you actually need the values or order of the elements preceding or following the median?  (Other than those *immediately* preceding and following when the total number of elements is even.)

Comment: `memcpy(arr+(i*INTSIZE), nums2, INTSIZE*(nums2Size-c2));` change to `memcpy(arr+(i*INTSIZE), nums2+c2*INTSIZE, INTSIZE*(nums2Size-c2));`

Comment: @JohnBollinger I hadn't implemented it since the code would be the same (with the nums1 and nums2 terminology switched) and I was working on getting the specific test case of nums1 = [1,2] and nums2 = [3,4]

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating your addresses wrong in `memcpy`.  Since `arr` as an `int *`, you're adding a number of *integers* to advance the pointer, not a number of bytes.

One way to fix this is to just let the compiler calculate the addresses:

```
memcpy(&arr[i], &nums2[c2], INTSIZE*(nums2Size-c2));
```

Or, sticking with the pointer math,

```
memcpy(arr + i, nums2 + c2, INTSIZE*(nums2Size-c2));
```

The last parameter is the number of bytes to copy, so the count of integers needs to be modified into a number of bytes.

In both cases, I've adjusted the second parameter to start copying from the correct element in the `nums2` array.

Then ask yourself:  What happens if `c2` reaches `nums2Size`?  You're not currently handling that case.